# Instant toString prepends plus

Tags: java, java-8, tostring, java-time

We have records in our datastore that have effective & expiry time. This information is stored using the string representation of `Instant`.

There are some records that would never expire. But since the value for expiry date is mandatory, we decided to store string representation of `Instant.MAX`.

So far so good. We have search use-case to return all the records that are active within the input time range `[s,e]`. We query the datastore and return all such records `[Si, Ei]` which satisfy the condition `Si < s && e < Ei` Note that string representations are being compared here.

Now the problem is that `+` is being prepended to the string representation of `Instant.MAX`. This is failing the condition `e < Ei` since `ASCII('+') < ASCII(digit)`.

I've written a piece of code to know after which `second`, the `+` starts getting prepended:

```
Long e = Instant.now().getEpochSecond()*1000;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.println(e + "->" + Instant.ofEpochMilli(e));
    e *= 10;
}
```

which prints:

```
1471925168000->2016-08-23T04:06:08Z
14719251680000->2436-06-07T17:01:20Z
147192516800000->6634-05-07T02:13:20Z
1471925168000000->+48613-06-14T22:13:20Z
14719251680000000->+468404-07-08T06:13:20Z
```

I've the option of truncating the `+` before persisting in datastore. I'm more interested in why this is happening and how can we explicitly avoid it?

Comment: The leading plus-sign is valid ISO-8601-format for all years beyond 9999. IMHO it is a little bit questionable to use a finite value (Instant.MAX) for realizing an infinite boundary or to rely on string comparisons. Can you just not retrieve the instants from db and query in your application server layer based on instant object comparison? Or you could store elapsed seconds (as numbers) in your db/store.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Comparison should take place in DB itself and the only allowed comparisons are for Integers & Strings. I've used string representation instead of epoch seconds so that it looks more readable when the data is manually queried.

Comment: It's sad that the ISO committee chose + as a prefix for years beyond 9999. A nice property of the ISO format is that the standard ASCII/unicode string ordering and the time ordering coincide, which is violated by the + sign. Any letter would have preserved it beyond 9999. With a few more tweaks, extending this to dates before 0000 looks possible as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer to your question 'why?' is hidden in the implementation of `DateTimeFormatterBuilder.InstantPrinterParser.format()` (I left out irrelevant code for brevity):

```
// use INSTANT_SECONDS, thus this code is not bound by Instant.MAX
Long inSec = context.getValue(INSTANT_SECONDS);
if (inSec >= -SECONDS_0000_TO_1970) {
    // current era
    long zeroSecs = inSec - SECONDS_PER_10000_YEARS + SECONDS_0000_TO_1970;
    long hi = Math.floorDiv(zeroSecs, SECONDS_PER_10000_YEARS) + 1;
    long lo = Math.floorMod(zeroSecs, SECONDS_PER_10000_YEARS);
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(lo - SECONDS_0000_TO_1970, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC);
    if (hi > 0) {
         buf.append('+').append(hi);
    }
    buf.append(ldt);
}
```

As you can see, it checks boundaries of 10000-year periods and if the value exceeds at least one of them, it adds `+` and the quantity of such periods.

So, to prevent such behaviour, keep your maximum date within the epoch bounds, don't use `Instant.MAX`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to support sorting of string value, you need to ensure that you never exceed the year range of `0000` to `9999`.

That means to replace `Instant.MAX` with `Instant.parse("9999-12-31T23:59:59Z")`, which is also the maximum date most RDBMS's can handle.

To skip the parse step, use `Instant.ofEpochSecond(253402300799L)`.

---

However, rather than setting a "max" value for an open-ended date range, use a null value, i.e. there *is* no "max" value.

You would when change your `Si < s && e < Ei` condition to:

`Si < s && (Ei == null || e < Ei)`

Also, you're likely missing an `=` in that condition. In Java, ranges are usually lower-inclusive, upper-exclusive (e.g. see [`substring()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-), [`subList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-), etc.), so use this:

`Si <= s && (Ei == null || e < Ei)`

Comment: The datastore in question is DynamoDB and there needs to be a non-null value for the range query to work.

Answer (score 2):

The default behavior for most date formatters is to prepend a plus sign to a year if it's longer than 4 digits. This applies to both parsing and formatting. See for example [`Year.parse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Year.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) and the **Year** section [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns). The format is pretty much baked into `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT` (see @AndrewLygin's answer), so if you want to alter it, you'll have to convert your instant to a `ZonedDateTime` (since instants don't have natural fields) and use a custom formatter:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .parseCaseInsensitive()
        .appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR, 4, 10, SignStyle.NORMAL)
        .appendLiteral('-')
        .appendValue(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 2)
        .appendLiteral('-')
        .appendValue(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 2)
        .appendLiteral('T')
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_TIME)
        .toFormatter();

String instant = formatter
        .format(Instant.ofEpochMilli(e).atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC));
```

The key here is `SignStyle.NORMAL`, instead of the default `SignStyle.EXCEEDS_PAD` which would prepend `+` if the year goes over the 4-digit padding.

Comment: One big pitfall, this code will not work for `Instant.MAX`. Have tested it myself, try it, too. Reason is the strange choice for the supported value range of `Instant` which exceeds the supported range of classes like `LocalDate` in terms of years. Otherwise a good idea to choose an appropriate sign style.